# Javascript if statement with AND and OR

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm using a browser plugin for jQuery that retrieves the browser name and version. Anyway I'm trying to display a message if the user is using a certain browser and/or a certain version. Here is what I'm using:

```
if (($.browser.name == "msie" && $.browser.version <= "8.0") || $.browser.name == "safari" || $.browser.name == "opera") {
    // Do something
}
```

It all works fine except the error displays in IE9 and it isn't supposed to. I want it to display only if it's version 8.0 or below that. What's wrong with the statement?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I'm now using the $.browser.versionNumber but it still doesn't work. Like this:

```
if (($.browser.name == "msie" && $.browser.versionNumber <= "8") || $.browser.name == "safari" || $.browser.name == "opera") {
    // Do something
}
```

$.browser.versionNumber retrieves a number. In this case, if I'm using IE9, it will send "9".

Comment: show us the plugin name.

Comment: http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

Comment: At least you can't use `<=` on a string `$.browser.version <= "8.0"`.

Comment: `$.browser.versionNumber` would be a better choice

Comment: Sharing the error message would be helpful.

Comment: There's no error message. The notice is showing in IE9 though, and it's only supposed to show in IE8 or below that as I stated.

Comment: You are comparing a `string` with an `int`! Use `8` instead of `"8"`. Although `(9 <= "8") == false` so it should be fine this way too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>As others have already stated, there is no `<=` operator defined on strings.</s>

There is a `<=` operator on strings but it is not the one you need. For example:

```
alert('2' <= '10'); // this yields false.
```

The solution would be using `$.browser.versionNumber`:

> browser.versionNumber: The version of the browser (note, as an integer).

Like this:

```
if (($.browser.name == "msie" && $.browser.versionNumber <= 8) || $.browser.name == "safari" || $.browser.name == "opera") {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: <= is a defined operator for strings.  It just doesn't work the same way as it does on numbers.

Comment: It worked. Using versionNumber and removing "" from the 8 made the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @StevenMoseley thanks for the correction, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

be    aware that comparing strings gives different results than comparing numbers

```
  $.browser.version <= "8.0"
```

for example

```
  "10.0" < "8.0"
```

maybe you are only intrested in the major version number, then you could use parseInt to extract that.

Comment: I'm now using the versionNumber string. How can I use the parseInt?

Answer (score 0):

Is IE9 running in compatibility and/or quirks mode on your website?

This may mislead the plugin into thinking you're running an older version.

Comment: No. If I print the version number it will print 9.

Comment: In which case, you should be testing against `<= 8` rather than `<= "8"`

Answer (score -1):

You should not use "<=" on a string :

```
if (($.browser.name == "msie" && $.browser.version <= 8) || $.browser.name == "safari" || $.browser.name == "opera") {
// Do something
}
```